# Reverse a LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a linked list and save it into another new liked list and delete the old one, but I get an error when compiling.. Here's the function..

```
LinkedList LinkedList::reverse(){
    LinkedList L2;
    Node * temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        Node * del=NULL;
        L2.addAtFront(temp->data);
        del=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
        delete del;
     }
     return L2;

}
```

Comment: This is a typical use-case for algorithm x! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: [Closely related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45918/489).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this if (and only if) you no longer need the original linked list!**

Instead of using `addAtFront` which is less cheap (because you need to allocate memory for new nodes and destroy the old ones), you can **reuse** the nodes and the `LinkedList` (after all, you were going to **delete the original one**, and simply set the pointers:

```
LinkedList LinkedList::reverse(){
    Node* na = head;
    Node* nb = NULL;
    Node* nc = NULL;
    if(na == NULL) {
        return this;
    }
    nb = na->next;
    na->next = NULL;
    while(nb != NULL){
        nc = nb->next;
        nb->next = na;
        na = nb;
        nb = nc;
    }
    tail = head; //if you keep a tail?
    head = na;
    return this;
}
```

The method works as follows, you scan over the original list and use three references: `na`, `nb` and `nc`. Who are organized in the order of the original list.

Now you know for sure `na` and `nb` are effective in the `while` loop. You first ensure that you will keep a reference to `nb`'s next by storing it in `nc`. Next you set the `->next` of `nb` to `na` (originally `na->next` was `nb`), so now it is reversed.

Then you shift in the process: `na` becomes the old `nb`, `nb` the old `nc`. You keep repeating this until you reach the end of the linked list.

You need to do two additional tasks:
 - Set the original `head`'s `->next` to `null`, otherwise you will construct a cycle; and
 - Set the tail of the original `LinkedList` to the `head`.

If you maintain a `tail`, you will first need to set it to the head.

Comment: Can't you run it in a terminal? Where is the source code of your linked list? Then people can debug it as well...

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++.. When I run the program it stops working and opens a file called Makefile.win.. I have no idea what that file is or why it stops working .. Even though the other functions are written properly :/

Comment: `Makefile` is a program that calls the compiler with the proper flags...